# EOFError and dropped values during Python Named pipe operations

Tags: python, named-pipes

I'm writing to a pipe and reading it again in a separate class.

I am opening up the pipe, and sending through an iteration between 1 to 1000. The receiving pipe gets this and returns the values. There are two problems I'm having:

1. There are random EOFErrors occurring in between the transmission
2. The Receiving pipe function only seems to start printing from 30+

My code as follows:

```
for num in range(1000):
    classMan.give('data.fifo', num + 1)

def give(self, path, value):
    pipe = open(path, "wb")
    pickle.dump(values, pipe)
    pipe.close()
```

my recieving function as follows:

```
def pipeListener(self, path):
    try:      
        pipe = open(path, "rb")
        data = pickle.load(pipe)
        pipe.close()
        return data
    except EOFError:
        print("EOFError")
        return None
```

When the code is run, I get output like this:

```
python3 pipe_learning.py
EOFError
21
24
EOFError
27
28
29
30
31
32
```

Where have I gone wrong? I'm relatively new to Pipes, but this doesn't seem normal, especially the random nature of the EOFErrors.

Comment: I was expecting the EOFError to be at the end of read operations, not at the start

Comment: You are using the named pipe as a binary file, feeding it to `pickle.loads()`. Try to read yourself from the file you open (using `pipe.read()` for example), and check that you are indeed getting the full written data (by comparing lengths, for eample). Are you runnnig the listener and publisher in different threads or different processes ?

Comment: Yes the listener and publisher are on different processes, using the same file though

Comment: Your `except` masks any useful diagnostics.  Could you take it out entirely, or change it so that we see which function exactly is producing the error, or at least refactor it to print the precise error message, if not the full traceback?

Comment: Having said that, I'm guessing you end up reading a partial pickle.  Maybe you should read *until* you get an EOF to make sure you have all the data.

Comment: @tripleee the error being given is "EOFError: Ran out of input"

Comment: And if a proper traceback would reveal that this comes from `pickle.load()` because `pipe` doesn't contain a full object after a single read, that would settle it; but without full diagnostics, we are still speculating.