# Named Pipes in Linux with Python read/write miss some lines of text

Tags: python, linux, pipe, named-pipes

I am learning how to use named pipes to pass data between processes. To test it out, I wrote two Python scripts, which I called `pipewriter.py` and `pipereader.py`, and a named pipe called `my_pipe` (using `mkfifo my_pipe`), all in the same directory. The Python scripts are included below.

### `pipewriter.py`

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
for i in range(1, 5):
  with open('my_pipe', 'a') as outfile:
    outfile.write(f'Hello {i}\n')
    if i==4:
      outfile.write('\n')

print('Done')
```

### `pipereader.py`

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
while True:
  with open('my_pipe', 'r') as infile:
    input = infile.read()
    print(input,end="")
```

The problem is that `pipereader.py` sometimes misses some of the lines output by `pipewriter.py`. When I run `./pipereader.py` in one terminal and `./pipewriter.py` in another, then the lines written are

```
Hello 1
Hello 2
Hello 3
Hello 4
```

But if I run `./pipewriter.py; ./pipewriter.py; ./pipewriter.py` (with `pipereader.py` running in a different terminal), then the output of `pipereader.py` sometimes looks like this:

```
Hello 1
Hello 2
Hello 3
Hello 1    <- Missing "Hello 4"
Hello 2
Hello 3
Hello 4

Hello 1
Hello 2
Hello 3
Hello 4
```

How can I figure out why the lines are disappearing and ensure it doesn't happen?

By rewriting `./pipewriter.py` to open `my_pipe` only once for each execution, I can seemingly prevent missing lines. Still, I'm not sure if this is just a matter of reducing the frequency of missing lines, so I've just "gotten lucky" the several times I've tested it.

### `pipewriter.py` (Modified)

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3 
with open('my_pipe', 'a') as outfile:
  for i in range(1, 5):
    outfile.write(f'Hello {i}\n')
  outfile.write('\n')

print('Done')
```

### Edit: Output When using an Input Argument per [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77616578/named-pipes-in-linux-with-python-read-write-miss-some-lines-of-text/77616642?noredirect=1#comment136834095_77616642)

#### Modified pipewriter.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import sys

for i in range(1, 5):
  with open('my_pipe', 'a') as outfile:
    outfile.write(f'Hello {sys.argv[1]} {i}\n')
    if i==4:
      outfile.write('\n')

print('Done')
```

#### Output 1 of `./pipewriter.py A; ./pipewriter.py B; ./pipewriter.py C`

```
Hello A 1
Hello A 2
Hello A 3
Hello A 4

Hello B 1
Hello B 2
Hello B 3
Hello B 4

Hello C 1
Hello C 2
Hello C 3
```

#### Output 2 of `./pipewriter.py A; ./pipewriter.py B; ./pipewriter.py C`

```
Hello A 1
Hello A 2
Hello A 3
Hello A 4

Hello B 1
Hello B 2
Hello B 3
Hello B 4

Hello C 1
Hello C 2
```

Comment: When I run your script, sometimes `pipewriter.py` crashes with a "Broken pipe" error during `outfile.write("\n")`. These are the cases when `pipereader.py` gets a partial read.

Comment: On trying some more, there isn't that correlation between the error and the partial reads.

Comment: [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38733563/eoferror-and-dropped-values-during-python-named-pipe-operations) seems to be the same problem.